# How to Insert a variable in the middle of a string

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, webview

Starting off I have UTFS.

Trying to insert a variable in the middle of string to populate a web view form without using a string by append and making the code huge.  My current code is

> NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@" document.DetailView.innerHTML;"   @"document.getElementsByName('user_name')[0].value = 'somuser';"
>                          @"document.getElementsByName('user_password')[0].value = 'somevar';" 
>                         @"document.DetailView.submit();" ]

I have tried

> NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@" document.DetailView.innerHTML;"   @"document.getElementsByName('user_name')[0].value = '%@';"
>                          @"document.getElementsByName('user_password')[0].value = 'somevar';" 
>                         @"document.DetailView.submit();" , txtField.text];

But it throws me a build error(specifically it's looking for "]").  I'm guessing I will have to slowly build the string using stringbyappend but i'm hoping for a little luck that someone will have encountered this or have a workaround for it.  This seemed so simple in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place variables into a string with `stringWithFormat:`.  In your case, the following would work:

```
NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.DetailView.innerHTML; document.getElementsByName('user_name')[0].value = '%@'; document.getElementsByName('user_password')[0].value = 'somevar'; document.DetailView.submit();" , txtField.text]];
```

There is an additional bug in your code in that you don't properly encode the text field value - consider what would happen if the user entered an apostrophe.

However building up JavaScript in this way isn't a great approach.  Consider factoring out the JavaScript into an external JavaScript file - this will make it much easier to read and write.

Comment: Can you throw me a bone on how to get this done?  BTW even if it's UTFS I still appreciate the response.

Comment: You can find the path to files in your bundle using `NSBundle`.  `NSString` provides convenience methods to read files in as strings.  Alternatively, you *may* be able to include the JavaScript file directly by dynamically adding a `<script> element to the document.

Answer (score 1):

NSString's `stringWithFormat` is generally the correct approach for this.

Example:

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"somejavascript.var = '%@'", otherString];`

The error I see first in both your first and second examples is here: `...TML;" @"doc...`